# git show previous commit that modified a file without git log

Tags: git, vim-fugitive

In git we can easily construct revisions pointing to previous commits like `HEAD~` `HEAD^` and show files on those revisions like

```
git show HEAD~:myfile
```

What is the syntax to show the previous version of `myfile` without first consulting `git log` to get the commit hash?

I also use `fugitive` in `vim` and sometimes needs to open a file's previous version using `:Gedit`. But I don't know what to supply as argument.

Comment: It seems not possible. The "previous version" is ambiguous. For a merge commit, which ancestor is its previous version?

Comment: @ElpieKay I assume the question is looking at the first parent.

Comment: @JosephK.Strauss yes. The first parent is good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git show $(git log -m --first-parent --format=%H HEAD~ -2 -- path/to/file | tail -1):path/to/file
```

Note: This solution requires you to specify the path twice, and can be quite verbose to type every time. An alias would perhaps be better.

```
git config alias.prev '! f(){ git show $(git log -m --first-parent --format=%H HEAD~ -2 -- "$1" | tail -1):"$1"; }; f'
```

To get the previous hash:

```
git config alias.prevhash '! f(){ git rev-parse $(git log -m --first-parent --format=%H HEAD~ -2 -- "$1" | tail -1):"$1"; }; f'
```

Comment: Thanks. But this still uses git log. Is this the only way of obtaining that hash?